# Function to convert String to Decimal value?

Tags: apex, string, decimal, convert

I need to convert `String` into `Decimal`. the [isNumeric()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isNumeric) method is retuning `false` if value is `Decimal`. Another alternate:

```
try
{
    Integer x = Integer.valueOf(myString);
}
catch (exception e)
{
    // it's not an Integer, try something else
}
```

Is there any other way to convert `Decimal` into `String`?

Note: value which is coming can be `Integer` or `String`.

Comment: What part of this are you actually having trouble with?  Are there any examples that aren't working?  The documentation is pretty clear on what you can do with Decimals/Integers/Strings.

Comment: Nick thanx for comment. i wanted to check is string is having Numeric value or Decimal value. i dont want to use Try Catch. is there anything else which i can try?  my code is like this `if (searchKey.isNumeric() && Decimal.valueof(searchKey.trim()) <= SISConstants.MAX_LOAN_AMT)`

Comment: Why don't you want to use a try/catch block?  It seems logical to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.:)

```
    public static Boolean isValidLoanValue(String value) {
        String amtRegEx = '£{0,1}\\d{1,16}.{0,1}\\d*';
        Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(amtRegEx);
        Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(value);
        Boolean flag = MyMatcher.matches();
        return flag; 
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

IsNumeric() method works for only Integer value not for decimal value

like this

```
String str = '10';
system.debug('===strToDec=='+str.isNumeric());
```

This will return true.

---

```
String str = '10.25';

Decimal strToDec = decimal.valueOf(str);

system.debug('===strToDec=='+strToDec);

String decToStr = String.valueOf(strToDec);

system.debug('===decToStr=='+decToStr);
```

Run this code in developer console ad check output.

---

In you case do something like. First convert string to numeric then check and again convert string into decimal for future use

```
String  str = '10.25';
Integer intCheck = Integer.ValueOf(str);
Decimal decVal = Decimal.ValueOf(str);
if(String.ValueOf(intCheck ).isNumeric())
//use decVal here
```

Don't understand why you need this.

Comment: Your first solution wont work for Decimal value and i already mentioned value can be string also so it will throw Exception.

Comment: @KuldeepParihar as I mentioned `IsNumeric()` return true for Integer value and for decimal return false

Answer (score 3):

As Nick Cook suggested, this is one of the rare cases when catching the exception is probably the cleanest approach:

```
Object o = ...
Decimal d;
try {
    d = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(o));
} catch (TypeException e) {
    d = null;
    // In a controller you might add the exception message e.g. "Invalid decimal: abc"
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: May be worth adding a null check for o ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the decimal range for all the inputs you can directly hardcode the divider

```
String str= '450.00';
//Remove the delimiter . from the value and divide it with the 100 and scale it to 2 decimal again
System.debug((Decimal.valueOf(str.remove('.'))/100).setscale(2));
```

If inputs decimal varies then find the dividervalue dynamically:

```
String str= '450.00';
Double tenVal=10;
Double multiplier=str.length()-1-str.indexOf('.');
Double dividerval=Math.pow(tenVal,multiplier);
System.debug((Decimal.valueOf(str.remove('.'))/dividerval).setscale(Integer.valueof(multiplier)));
```